# Angular ng-model bound from nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This must have been already done, and I am missing something about how Angular works on that point.

In short, I have `<select ng-model><option ng-repeat/></select>` and I don't know how to give it a default value at page load.

View:

```
<div ng-ctrl="MyCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="submitChoice()">
    <select ng-model='choice'>
      <option ng-repeat='choice in choices' value='{{choice.id}}'>{{choice.id}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Way 1**: When user updates the view (select the 'choice' he wants), the `$scope` used in MyCtrl gets it and I can perform whatever I want with it:

**Way 2**: But if, the other way round, I want to programmatically set the default value for the choices  from the controller (at start), it can't change the value displayed:

```
function MyCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.submitChoice = function() {return;}; // Way1: OK!
  $scope.choice = choice4;                    // Way2: Doesn't change the view!!
}
```

I guess it's because each element in ng-repeat has its own scope (fyi if I hardcode options in view instead of a ng-repeat, it works well).

In way 1 the inner scope selected by the use emits `choice` to the upper scope, if I understand well. But I have no idea how to do way 2.

Is it doable in a simple way? Is a directive necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be better off using the `ng-options` directive with the `select` directive. Using select + ngRepeat has all sort of limitations and is better avoided. Is there any particular reason for generating options with `ngRepeat`?

If you could share more code (especially the structure of your data model) I might be able to provide more info.

Comment: That's it! I got lost in the doc, didn't see it. In two words, what I needed is simply `<select ng-model="choice" ng-options="c.id for c in choices"></select>`